# iOS Auto Layout: Align the edge of one button to the center of another button?

Tags: ios, autolayout

So I have two UIButtons that I'd like to align, but not specifically the edges.  I would like to align the (left) edge of one button to the (horizontal) center of another button.  So I want it to look like this:

[image: Button1]

How would I do this AutoLayout in Interface Builder and/or programatically?  I hope this isn't too much of a beginner question, but iOS AutoLayout can be so confusing at times...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In IB, create any horizontal constraint between the two buttons. For example, align their centers. Then, select the new constraint object and the Size inspector. There, you can change which attributes are aligned. Select the leading edge of the top button. Now the CenterX of the bottom button is aligned to the leading edge of the top button.

Comment: Thanks!  I knew it was something simple like that...  :)

Comment: Note: You must double click the constraint object in the Size Inspector for the "Leading Alignment Display" to show up for adjustment. ... That tripped me up for a bit.